# How to apply gradient colours to the background of the active dots of paginator in react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, gradient, linear-gradients

Apply gradient colours to the background of the active dots of paginator in react native.
I tried with most of the npm packages but most of them available for native only.
I want generic for both ios and android.Given my code as well.

```
  export default Paginator = ({ data, scrollX, index }) => {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <View style={styles.paginatorView}>
      {data.map((_, i) => {
        const inputRange = [(i - 1) * width, i * width, (i + 1) * width];
        const dotwidth = scrollX.interpolate({
          inputRange,
          outputRange: [10, 40, 10],
          extrapolate: "clamp",
        });
        const opacity = scrollX.interpolate({
          inputRange,
          outputRange: [0.4, 1, 0.4],
          extrapolate: "clamp",
        });
        return (
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              styles.dot,
              {
                width: dotwidth,
                opacity: opacity,
              },
              i === index && styles.dotActive,
            ]}
            key={i.toString()}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dot: {
    height: moderateScale(10),
    borderRadius: moderateScale(5),
    backgroundColor: COLORS.grey,
    marginHorizontal: moderateScale(5),
  },
  dotActive: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.blue,
  },
  paginatorView: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: moderateScale(65),
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Currently I had used static of Blue color,I want to make it  gradient of two colors.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have also made a linear button using this library.
it works fine, you need to take care of its setup.

**You can use this library**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient

==> You can use it like this.

```
return (
   <LinearGradient colors={backgroundColor}>
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              styles.dot,
              {
                width: dotwidth,
                opacity: opacity,
              },
              i === index && styles.dotActive,
            ]}
            key={i.toString()}
          />
</LinearGradient>
        );
```

Comment: yes but how can I use this library in my case? @Ankit Vora

Comment: Thanks @Ankit but it is not working according to my requirement.